# How to deallocate a static block in java?

Tags: java

I need to deallocate a static block.
In my project i have to use a static block.
Once i am login to project it works fine.
After i am logout my application.
Static block still have the same value.

Sample code:

```
public class Demo {

public static String a;
static {
a = "Test";
}

}
```

Comment: Your example code is at least missing a type for var. Is setting `var = null` on your logout an option?

Comment: Well they arent gonna change themselves..

Comment: Why would you expect it to change? What do "login" and "logout" mean in your question - you need to show more code.

Comment: No, you need to assign a static field.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: while login to my application i m reading variable a vlaue and i m change variable a as a= "sample";@shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you logout, you need to manually set these vars to what you want (either null or 0). They will not autmatically go away.